# tikz: coordinate arithmetic when drawing an angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, angle, tikz-angles

I can draw an angle like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate(O1) at (1, 1);
  \coordinate(O) at (1, 0);
  \coordinate(O2) at (0, 0);                                                                                                          
  \draw pic [draw, angle radius=1cm] {angle=O1--O--O2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

Now I want to perform coordinate arithmetic when drawing an angle:

```
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=1cm] {angle=$(O) + (0, 1)$--(O)--$(O) + (-1, 0)$};
```

This approach fails while a similar approach when drawing a line succeeds:

```
\draw (O) -- ($(O) + (1, 1)$);
```

How to perform coordinate arithmetic when drawing an angle?

Comment: You cannot like that, angle only works on named coordinates. Do do your calculations on named coordinates and the use those names in the angle argument

Comment: @daleif Would you like to write up an answer? You can quote the manual for support, which says "*The three points `<A>`, `<B>`, and `<C>` must be the names of nodes or coordinates; you cannot use direct
coordinates like “`(1,1)`” here.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can't. The manual says

> The three points `<A>`, `<B>`, and `<C>` must be the names of nodes or coordinates; you cannot use direct coordinates like `(1,1)` here.

Hence, calculate and name the coordinates first.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate(O) at (1, 0);
  \coordinate (O2) at ($(O) + (0, 1)$);
  \coordinate (O3) at ($(O) + (-1, 0)$);
  \draw pic [draw, angle radius=1cm] {angle=O2--O--O3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```